# Calling powershell function with parameter from .cmd or .bat file

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script which is a complete function taking parameters (e.g. function name (param) { } ) and below this is a call to the function, with the parameter.

I want to be able to call this function in its .ps1 file, passing in the parameter. How would I be able to package a call to the function via a .bat or .cmd file? I am using Powershell v2.0.

Answer (score 17):

You should use so called "dot-sourcing" of the script and the command with more than one statement: dot-sourcing of the script + call of the function with parameters.

The test script Test-Function.ps1:

```
function Test-Me($param1, $param2)
{
 "1:$param1, 2:$param2"
}
```

The calling .bat file:

```
powershell ". .\Test-Function.ps1; Test-Me -Param1 'Hello world' -Param2 12345"

powershell ". .\Test-Function.ps1; Test-Me -Param1 \"Hello world\" -Param2 12345"
```

Notes: this is not a requirement but I would recommend enclosing the entire command text with double quotation marks escaping, if needed, inner quotation marks using CMD escape rules.

Comment: This worked great. Just needed to wrap the path of the ps file with `'` so that spaces in the path don't prevent it from working. So `powershell.exe ". 'C:\path to\Test-Function.ps1'; Test-Me -Param1 'Hello world' -Param2 12345"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you have to do is name the parameters in the call to the script like the following:

```
powershell.exe Path\ScripName -Param1 Value1 -Param2 Value2
```

Param1 and Param2 are actual parameter names in the function signature.

Enjoy!

Comment: How do I call the actual function though? Will this call my function? What if I have >1 function in the same .ps1 file with the signature in terms of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

To call a PowerShell function from cmd or batch with arguments you need to use the `-Commmand` Parameter or its alias `-C`.

Romans answer will work with PowerShell 5.1 for example but will fail for PowerShell 7.1.

Quote from an issue I left on GitHub on why the same command didn't work is:

> So as to support Unix shebang lines, pwsh's CLI now defaults to the -File parameter (which expects only a script-file path), whereas powershell.exe default to -Command / -c.
> To make your commands work with pwsh, you must use -Command / -C explicitly.

So if you have a PowerShell file `test.ps1` with:

```
function Get-Test() {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = 'The test string.')]
    [String]$stringTest
    )
  Write-Host $stringTest
  return
}
```

And the batch file will then be:

```
rem Both commands are now working in both v5.1 and v7.1.
rem v7.1
"...pathto\pwsh.exe" -NoExit -Command ". '"...pathto\test.ps1"'; Get-Test ""help me"""
rem v5.1
powershell.exe -NoExit -Command ". '"...pathto\test.ps1"'; Get-Test ""help me"""
```

The quotes around `...pathto\test.ps1` are a must if your `.ps1` contains spaces.

The same goes for `...pathto\pwsh.exe`

---

Here's the Github issue I posted in full:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15281